# How to check if all arrow functions are true?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm creating a form validator. And I only want to go to the next page if all four validators are true. I've created four arrow functions for the validators.

```
const nameIsValid = name => !name.match(nameRegX);
const mailIsValid = mail => mail.match(mailRegX);
const phoneIsValid = phone => phone.match(phoneRegX);
const postalIsValid = postal => postal.match(postRegX);
```

Every arrow function is tied to a event listener onchange in the input. This looks like this.

```
inputs[0].onchange = function() {
    var validateName = nameIsValid(name.value);
    animator(validateName, 0, isNameTrue);  
}
```

Then all four times inputs[1], [2] & [3].

In the function you see the third argument of the animator is isNameTrue. These are variables I've declared before the function with this:

```
var isNameTrue = false;
var isMailTrue = false;
var isPhoneTrue = false;
var isPostalTrue = false;
```

Then if the arrow function is true, I want to turn these values true as well, which I do by this function.

```
function animator(validity, i, isTrue){
    var error = document.querySelectorAll(".form-error");
    var correct = document.querySelectorAll(".form-display");

    if (validity){
        correct[i].classList.add("animate")
        error[i].classList.remove("animate")
        isTrue = true;


    } else {
        error[i].classList.add("animate")
        correct[i].classList.remove("animate")
        isTrue = false;
    }
}
```

Then when the user clicks on the submit button, I only want the next action when all four are true.

```
inputs[4].onclick = function(){
    if (isNameTrue && isMailTrue && isPhoneTrue && isPostalTrue){
        console.log("We are all true");
    } else {
        console.log("We are not true!")
    }

}
```

However, they're always false.

How can I properly check if all four are true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boolean` are passed by value,hence, the reference is not same which means even if you change the value in the `animator` function, the value of the variable passed will not change.

You can update your code to following

```
inputs[0].onchange = function() {
    var validateName = nameIsValid(name.value);
    isNameTrue = validateName; // <---- Set your value here and do not pass to the function
    animator(validateName, 0);  
}
```

Comment: @hyenax - Glad to help you :)